# How to remove trailing dot from Drupal Cookie

Tags: php, drupal, cookies, drupal-7

I have a website which has two parts. One is written in Drupal and other in Java. I need to synchronise the cookie they have using to sync the last access time and prevent inactivity in both sites. I hvae comearound a problem that is Drupal sets my Cookie Domain as `.mydomainname.com`. But when i update the the Max Age of that cookie from Java, it sets the domain as `mydomainname.com`. So i can't able to sync these cookies. Is there anyway in Drupal  so that I can prevent the trailing dot in Cookie.

Drupal - 7.2,
J2EE - 2.4,
Java - 1.6

Answer (score 2):

In the **settings.php** file there is a useful setting around line 338:

```
# $cookie_domain = '.example.com';
```

You can set here your cookie_domain. In fact it is the Java application that needs to set the cookie as .mydomainname.com because this is the [correct syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path).